# How add russian lang support and set english for table of contents caption?

Tags: pdftex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\author{Name Surname}
\title{LaTex Demo Document}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

    \section{first section}
        тест

    \subsection{sub section}
        тест

\end{document}
```

... generates document with cyrillic letters support and with captions on russian.

How to set table of contents caption to another language (
for ex., english) and save cyrillic letters support (without babel package document will not be compiled)?

Comment: I dont know how to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is super-easy.
Last language in `babel` languages list is default. And this last specified language is used during latex generates toc and other.

Thanks for replies, @touhami.

Answer (score 0):

A solution. Add `\let\oldcontentsname\contentsname \AtBeginDocument{\let\contentsname\oldcontentsname}` after babel

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\let\oldcontentsname\contentsname \AtBeginDocument{\let\contentsname\oldcontentsname}

\author{Name Surname}
\title{LaTex Demo Document}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

    \section{first section}
        тест

    \subsection{sub section}
        тест

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{a4wide}


\author{Name Surname}
\title{LaTex Demo Document}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
%%% add from article.cls
\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\renewcommand\refname{References}
\renewcommand\indexname{Index}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
\renewcommand\partname{Part}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
%%%%%

  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

    \section{first section}
        тест

    \subsection{sub section}
        тест

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this  looks "bulky", and don't work for date in title.

Comment: may be i did not undestand your question well. Please edit it to be more clear.

Comment: I want to save support of russian letters and to make latex print toc, title and other generated by latex text in english.

For example, after compiling your code date in title is written in russian, but toc - in english.

Comment: ok, please add this request to your question.

Comment: I had try to compile your new code, but https://asciinema.org/a/4sqan2dp63xaszas3ro8k1vjl

Comment: Ooh so sorry it's `\renewcommand` not `\newcommand` i'll edit the answer.